# Huge error finding the numerical derivative

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods

There is a huge numerical error when finding the numerical derivative of $sin (x^7) $. What is the reason for this?

Comment: Can you give more detail on the method you used?

Comment: Use any Taylor series based method and the error is huge. Does this mean that these methods are suitable for $x $ lesso than 1?

Comment: What do you mean with "Taylor series based method", you only have the values of the function available? Is this the first derivative you are looking at? How do you measure the error, is the relative error also huge?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Please show the method you used along with input and outputs.

Comment: You are a sick perverted idiot Dantopa. Just use any method. Looks like the question went way over your head. By the way I used centered, forward and backward finite difference formulas. Anyway, the question has been answered below.

Comment: Hahaha. What a bunch of pathetic illiterate snobs. Who gives a damn about your vote. The question has been answered below. Looks like you guys never went to a good school and lack basic mathematical knowledge.

Answer (score 4):

If you're estimating the derivative using a difference quotient,

$$ f'(x) \approx \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} $$
by Taylor's theorem the error is $f''(c) h/2$ for some $c$ between $x$ and $x+h$.  In this case with $f(x) = \sin(x^7)$, $$f''(x) = 42 x^5 \cos(x^7) - 49 x^{12} \sin(x^7)$$
so if $x$ is much greater than $1$, that term in $x^{12}$ can be very large.

EDIT: You might note that better approximations can be used, although all of them will eventually have trouble.  For example, try

$$ f'(x) \approx \frac{3}{4} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{h} - \frac{3}{20} \frac{f(x+2h)-f(x-2h)}{h} + \frac{1}{60} \frac{f(x+3h)-f(x-3h)}{h} $$

At $x = 2$ with $h = 0.0001$, the error with this approximation is about $0.0000129$, while with $(f(x+h)-f(x))/h$ the error is about $-7.179$.